# C# Regular Expression need help

Tags: c#, regex, web-applications

I try to find a part of a search word in a string variable with regular expression.

Here is the string variable content :

```
string s_Var = "[ Object[Key='o_Module.Id'].Text ]"
```

[, ], ', ', and . always there , but not Key=, Object and Text. (Can be different). I want to determine the part between ' and ' like 'o_Module.Id'

I only want to take the part between ' and '

Can you help me to determine the pattern i need ?

Exemple :

```
string s_Original_Text = "[ Object[Key='o_Module.Id'].Text ]"
```

? = i don't know the value can be

[ ?[??'o_Module.?].? ]

Comment: Can you give some examples of strings that should match and strings that shouldn't?

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to substring from first index of `'` and then substring to next index of `'`?

Comment: yes it may be possible, but with the regex I also valid if the string is in the right format

Comment: if want to validate, then you are implying that the strings are NOT always present in the format indicated; in which case, we need some examples of bad data.

Comment: does `[ Object[Key='o_Module.Id'].Text ]"` look like a `Dictionary<int, string>` to anyone else? maybe you shouldn't be using the string var at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
var s = "[['o_Module.Id'].Text]"; 
//"[Object[Key='o_Module.Id'].Text]"; //ALSO MATCHES THIS
var r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(\[?.*\[?')(.*)('.*)");
var m = r.Match(s);
if (m.Success)
{
    //0 contains whole string
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value); //Prints o_Module.Id
}
```

Comment: but please do test it on lot of sample string to see if it really helps in validating the format otherwise as @Ed suggested you can just take substring of the subject string.

Comment: Do be careful if you are using the regular expression to ensure that the data is in the proper structure. The expression above would not catch data with errant quotes or brackets such as: [ Object[Key='o_Module.Id.Text' ] or [ Object[Key='o_Module.Id].Text' ]

Answer (score 3):

If the single quotes are always present in the form you have shown above, why not just look for the first index of ' using SubString?  From what I see in your description using regular expressions here is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should usually do it, assuming there's only ever one set of single-quotes:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("[ Object[Key='o_Module.Id'].Text ]", "'([^']*)'");
```

If you want to add that optional stuff:

```
result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("[ Object[Key='o_Module.Id'].Text ]", @"\[ (?:Object)?\[(?:Key=)?'([^']*)'\]\.(?:Text)? \]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\[[^']*?'([^']+)
```

The o_Module.id value would be in the first capturing group.